# vectorize XCORR - matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

How can I vectorize/speed-up the following code?

```
time=1:100;
arr1=rand(5,5,100);
arr2=rand(5,5,100);
for ii=1:5
    for jj=1:5

        [xc(ii,jj),lags] = xcorr(squeeze(arr1(ii,jj,:)),...
                          squeeze(arr2(ii,jj,:)));


    end
end
```

It finds the lag of maximum correlation between two matrices along the third dimension.

Comment: What does the nested loop do? It appears you only store the results for the last iteration. What is the desired result?

Comment: xcorr is heavy weight and already vectorized function. Try using it on GPU (gpuarray, etc). Your current code doesn't store intermediate result, please, review it.

Comment: @LuisMendo I edited the code

Comment: @shamalaia preallocate xc, it will speed up the code significantly (iterative array resize is a costly operation and can turn off some engine in-built optimizations)